# Drupal: Two-way communication between unregistered customer and admin

Tags: drupal

I need to setup a system where customers can choose to Request a Quote for a specific holiday package, where they will enter their personal details as well as their holiday requirements (number of rooms, etc.) and will then allow them to view a page which will have a threaded conversation between them and the admin (so the admin can reply to their quote request on the website).

The problem is that most customers won't be registered when they want to request a quote, so I was thinking that the Request a Quote page could silently register the customer as a user (using their personal details) on the same page where it asks for their holiday requirements.
The other option I can think of would be to not register them and just email them a unique URL where they can view their quote request and reply to the admin.

Could you point me in the right direction on how to do either of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Inline Registration](http://drupal.org/project/inline_registration) module: it allows anonymous users to create a node and register as user at the same time, using a single form.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new user you can use the `user_save`. To create a random password you can use the use the `user_password` function. The all that is left is to send a mail. Either create your own or use the standard one when users are created.

Comment: That sounds good, but now if someone returns to create a new quote then it will create a new account for them

Comment: Not if they are already logged in. You can log in the user at creation and keep them logged in until they logout themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to have a content type they fill out that looks like a form, but actually creates the node that is only visible to them and the administrators, comment enabled. Probably the quickest way. Then you have security in place so people can't see other peoples quotes.

Comment: How will it only be visible to the customer if they are not authenticated yet? I was thinking it would need to give them a secret URL to link to the node, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You could allow anonymous to create this content, and use hook_nodeapi to implement user create functions to check if they exist or not. The form would have an email address field in it.

Answer (score 0):

[Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) combined with [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) might work for this.